# wcf 3.5 REST service works with XML but not JSON response format

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json

I have a service contract with several operation contracts defined. I have added a new endpoint to expose my operations as a restful webservice. Moreover I've updated operation definitions so that they can be called in a RESTful way

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "product/getall")]   
    Product[] GetAll()
```

Everything works fine my products are returned as XML... but I'd like to use JSON instead. If i change the code to

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
UriTemplate = "product/getall")]   
Product[] GetAll()
```

Response to product/getall call is empty. No exception is thrown, but I have a bad feeling that WCF JSON implementation somehow cannot cope with serialization. Anyone had similar problem? Any suggestions? Is i t possible to use JSON.NET to serialize/deserialize my objects?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work - here's what I did.  First off, my environment is VS2010 and I was using the VS web server (Cassini).

I didn't change your method signature or your `WebInvoke` attribute.  The body of the `GetAll()` method is this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "product/getall")]
Product[] GetAll()
{
    Product[] prods = new Product[3] {
        new Product() { Name="Foo", Desc="Bar"},
        new Product() {Name="Ha", Desc="Ho"},
        new Product() {Name="Who", Desc="What"}
    };

    return prods;
}
```

The web.config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebApplication2.ProdServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="WebApplication2.ProdService">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication2.ProdServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication2.ProdService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Honestly, most of this is default out-of-the-box functionality.  The only thing I changed was changing the `endpointBehavior` to use `webHttp` instead of the default `enableWebScript`.  Other than that, it worked fine.

**EDIT (forgot the Product class)**: Here's the Product class - I decorated it with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember()]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public String Desc { get; set; }
}
```

This was my output:

```
[{"Desc":"Bar","Name":"Foo"},{"Desc":"Ho","Name":"Ha"},{"Desc":"What","Name":"Who"}]
```

My guess is that you are using `enableWebScript` in your web.config.  Change it to `webHttp` and see what happens.  The `enableWebScript` setting is used for more ASMX type of compatibility (I believe).  If you're returning JSON (which a lot of my GET service methods do), use `webHttp` (which is what I'm used to using).

Let me know what you get and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the WCF tracing and view the trace log.  That should pinpoint where the issue is.  You can configure your web.config with the following settings to enable tracing.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
      propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="C:\Web_tracelog.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
    <add initializeData="C:\Web_messages.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```